# VBA for loop ending early

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

If I'm iterating k = 1 to 100, I need to sometimes restart an iteration if a criteria isn't met. In this case, I'm creating a random number between 1 and 100, but if that number is below 51, I want the iteration to start over.

Right now the code is returning a variable number of values. Sometimes 1, sometimes 90.

Any ideas why?

```
Public k as long
Sub Example()

For k = 1 To 100
    Call ExampleExtended
Next k

End Sub


Sub ExampleExtended()
Dim Val As Integer

Val = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd)

If Val < 51 Then
    k = k - 1
    Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Print Val

End Sub
```

Comment: This is quite an easy program flow. What did you try to debug the program?

Comment: I made k a public variable and I'm still getting the same issue for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

k is considered a local variable for both subs in your example, so you're not updating k like you think you are. Either increase the scope of k (which I don't recommend) or make ExampelExtended() a function that returns something you can use in the calling sub.

Here is one way. Obviously the function is kind of overkill, but trying to show how you can use a function to return a value to the calling sub:

```
    Sub Example()
    Dim counter     As Integer, _
        randNumber   As Integer

    For counter = 1 To 100

        randNumber = RandomBetween(50, 100)
        Debug.Print randNumber

    Next counter

    End Sub


    Function RandomBetween(lowerBound As Integer, upperBound As Integer) As Integer
        RandomBetween = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(lowerBound, upperBound)
    End Function
```

Is this closer?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()
Dim counter     As Integer, _
    randNumber   As Integer

For counter = 1 To 100

    randNumber = RandomBetween(1, 100)


    If randNumber < 50 Then
        counter = counter - 1
    Else ' this is here just as a check...should only print 100 numbers
        Debug.Print randNumber
    End If

Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: My example isn't the best, but I need to have the randomization be between 1 and 100 but have a check between 51 and 100. I can't just randbetween 50,100

Comment: @Fubudis not sure if my edit is what you're after...but this will print 100 numbers, each over 50.

Comment: Found the problem:

My code was in fact looping through 100,000 times like I wanted it to , but the debug.print was only saying 34464 because I was trying to use a count function on an array. Apparently there's 65K limit on those.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this would be better suited by using a Do While loop. Do While makes a loop indefinate until a condition is met - in this case, until a random number is > 51. Like so:

```
val = 1
Do While val < 51
    Val = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd)
Loop
```

Although in your case, this could be further simplified by just forcing the random number to be between 51 & 100, like so [taken from here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/randomNumbers.aspx:

```
Dim Low As Double
Dim High As Double
Low = 51 '<<< CHANGE AS DESIRED
High = 100 '<<< CHANGE AS DESIRED
val = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop has at least 100 iterations, and 150 iterations on average !

However, the `Debug.Print Val` is called 50 times on average.
Therefore, you will almost always see less then 100 values in the console window.

(There's a `2^(-100)` chance of seeing 100 lines in the console window)

If you change your code to:

```
Public k as long
Sub Example()

For k = 1 To 100
    Call ExampleExtended
Next k

End Sub


Sub ExampleExtended()
Dim Val As Integer

Val = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd)

Debug.Print Val

If Val < 51 Then
    k = k - 1
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

The amount of time the loop is executed will be the same as the amount of lines you have in your console

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. 

I'm still having some trouble with my actual code though despite using this method. 

I'm iterating 100,000 times but I'm consistently getting 34,464 outputs. Is this a memory issue perhaps?

Comment: @Fubudis - Try changing `Val as Integer` to `Val as Long`. ...Edit: Err, maybe not `Val`, but I am betting your issue is due to using `Integer`, ["An Integer variable does not store fractional values, holds whole numbers from -32,768 to 32,767..."](http://spreadsheetsuperstar.com/vba-integer-variable-data-type/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use goto:

```
Sub Example()

For k = 1 To 100

Call ExampleExtended

Next k

End Sub


Sub ExampleExtended()
Dim Val As Integer
start:
Val = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd)

If Val < 51 Then
goto start
k = k - 1
Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Print Val

End Sub
```

see if it works

Comment: This code would cause an infinite loop, for certain

Comment: I wouldn't use `GoTo`, it's generally frowned upon unless absolutely necessary. In this case, there are solutions easily done without `GoTo`.

Comment: I agree, just thought it would be a simple macro with a simple solution.

Comment: @UriGoren no, it dont, just show up numbers higher than 51